# What is the AudioImporter for a song?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to work out what should be the name for the importer in the case of a song?

```
context.BuildAsset<AudioContent, SongContent>(new ExternalReference<AudioContent>(filename), "SongProcessor", null, "**AudioImporter**", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename));
```

Thanks,
Simon.

Comment: Did you just thank yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though it's **Mp3Importer**.